# Copy/Paste with Range(Cells(

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy and paste a dynamic Range. I try to run this code but it does not work.

Instead

> "Runtime error 1004"

appears.

```
Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 2)).Copy Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 2))
```

If I use `Range("A1:A5")`, it works fine.

Comment: You have to write same code twice for two destination.

Comment: @Harun24HR I think you misunderstood it: `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 2))` represents the range `A1:B10` not 2 single cells.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks. I was thinking OP wants to paste data to two different location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that VBA does not know in which worksheet these cells `Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 2)` are because you did not specify it. Therefore you get an error.

Make sure you specify a worksheet for **every** `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows` or `Columns` object. If you don't specify it Excel starts guessing which sheet you mean (based on the scope the code is written in), and it might assume something else than you did. In most cases a `Cells` without specifying a sheet will be the same as `ActiveSheet.Cells`.

So correct would be:

```
Worksheets("Data").Range(Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("Data").Cells(10, 2)).Copy Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(10, 2))
```

Or better:

```
Dim Source As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Set Source = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(10, 2))
End With

Dim Destination As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
    Set Destination = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(10, 2))
End With

Source.Copy Destination
```

or something like

```
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

wsSrc.Range(wsSrc.Cells(1, 1), wsSrc.Cells(10, 2)).Copy wsDest.Range(wsDest.Cells(1, 1), wsDest.Cells(10, 2))
```

Comment: Was about to write more or less the same, just 2 remarks: **(1)** Using `Set Source = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(10, 2)` could be an alternative. **(2)** For the destination it's sufficient to provide only the top left cell.

Comment: Ah, and a third remark: `Worksheets` should also be qualified, eg `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")`

Comment: @FunThomas Good points, I added `ThisWorkbook`. Of course `.Resize` would be a good option too. Depending on whether the cells are hard coded (like above) or retrieved in some other way (OP spoke about dynamic range), `.Resize` might be either esier or more cumbersome to use. If hard coded I would prefer `.Resize`.